# Eratosthenes’ sieve Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find primes in a specified range. We are given the following:

• initialization:
– create a list of boolean values of length n+1 (we want to check primes up to a value of n inclusive; we won’t do anything with positions 0 and 1, but it’s easier to index this way), which are all initially True
– initialize a counter to 2
– initialize an empty list for the results

• start a while loop that runs as long as the the counter defined above is less than or equal to n
– add the current value of the counter to the results list
– set the values of the boolean list to False for all multiples of the current counter value <= n; you can do this with a while or a for loop. For example if i=3 and n=10 you should set elements 6 and 9 of the list to False
– search forward for the next possibly-prime value:
∗ first increment the counter by 1
∗ while the counter is less than or equal to n and the corresponding element of the boolean
list is False, increment the counter by 1.
• return the results list

```
def eratos(n):
    """function_docstring"""
    prime=[True]*(n+1)
    # 0 and 1 are not considered prime.
    count=2
    result=list()
    while count<=n:
        count+=result
        while count<=n:
            prime=False
            count+=1
            while count<=n:
                n=False
                count+=1
print(eratos(1)==[])=True *i keep on getting False*
```

I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you share why it's "going wrong"?

Comment: function `eratos()` doesn't return anything. So, checking for empty list won't work. If you check for None instead, that would print True.
Also still there are some other bugs.

Comment: In the question it says that print(eratos(1)==[])=True but I get False

Comment: If `result` is a list, what is `count+=result` supposed to do? What does it even mean to add a list to an int? Also, you first make `prime` a list, and then turn around and make it the single value `False`. You seem to not understand what lists actually are.

Comment: I tried doing that it still doesnt work.

Comment: John, I was following the guideline presented to me. I am not sure as to why it says

Comment: " set the values of the boolean list to False" doesn't say "set the list itself to false".

Comment: Oh! I see what I did wrong. Thank you! still trying to get the hang of it.